# How to rotate the whole canvas with two fingers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using this function to scroll my drawing canvas with one finger:

```js
var targetStartX, targetStartY, touchStartX, touchStartY;

function onCanvasTouchscroll(event) {

  if (event.touches.length == 1) {

    targetStartX = parseInt(event.target.style.left);
    targetStartY = parseInt(event.target.style.top);
    touchStartX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    touchStartY = event.touches[0].pageY;


    var touchOffsetX = (event.touches[0].pageX - touchStartX) / 10,
      touchOffsetY = (event.touches[0].pageY - touchStartY) / 10; // Calculate touch

    setTimeout(function() {

      var touchOffsetX = (-event.touches[0].pageX + touchStartX) / 10,
        touchOffsetY = (-event.touches[0].pageY + touchStartY) / 10; // Calculate touch

      canvas.style.top = targetStartY + touchOffsetY + 'px';
      canvas.style.left = targetStartX + touchOffsetX + 'px';

    }, 200);
  }
}
```

I'd like to create a new function that rotates the entire canvas using two fingers. I've tried `canvas.rotate` in my code, but I don't think I used the right command.

Comment: something simular : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239443/kineticjs-rotate-an-image-with-a-two-finger-touch-gesture

Comment: the content..the whole canvas

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there isn't such a command !

First of all you need to modify your function to detect the 2 fingers touch event, then rotate your canvas.

```
function onCanvasTouchscroll( event )
{

    if(event.touches.length == 1)
    {
    targetStartX = parseInt(event.target.style.left);
    targetStartY = parseInt(event.target.style.top);
    touchStartX  = event.touches[0].pageX;
    touchStartY  = event.touches[0].pageY;

    var touchOffsetX = (event.touches[0].pageX - touchStartX)/10,
    touchOffsetY = (event.touches[0].pageY - touchStartY)/10; 

      setTimeout(function(){    
         var touchOffsetX = (-event.touches[0].pageX + touchStartX)/10,
         touchOffsetY = (-event.touches[0].pageY + touchStartY)/10;

         canvas.style.top = targetStartY + touchOffsetY + 'px';
         canvas.style.left = targetStartX + touchOffsetX + 'px'; 
      }, 200);
   }
   else if (event.touches.length > 1) // 2 fingers
   {
    var rotation = event.rotation;

      if (!rotation)
      {
      rotation = Math.arctan2(event.touches[0].pageY - event.touches[1].pageY,
      event.touches[0].pageX - event.touches[1].pageX) * 180 / Math.PI;
      }

   canvas.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
   }
}
```

PS : Don't forget to add prefixes for browsers and you should be done.

Comment: not working but thanks for the canvas.style.transform it rotates the canvas when i  give it a fixed value